# For a positive integer $ n$, $ P(n)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}.....+\frac{1}{2^n-1}$, then

Tags: induction

Four given options are:
$$A) P(100)<100$$ $$B) P(100)>100$$
$$C) P(200)<100$$ $$D) P(100)=150$$

Despite much try I am unable to find which option holds true. I am just unable to understand the question.
$$1+(1/2+1/3)+(1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7)+(1/8+....+1/15)+....+1/{(2^n)-1}$$
= $$1+(1/2+1/2²-1)+(1/4+1/5+1/6+1/2³-1)+.....+1/{(2^n) -1}$$
What to do next ?

Comment: I read your initial sum as $P(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{2^{n-1}} \frac 1i$.  Was this what you meant or did you intend something else?  The way you wrote it was not at all clear.

Comment: Regardless of what you meant, this question concerns the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and in that link you'll find some very good approximations.

Comment: HINT: group them together: $(1)+(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7})+...$

Comment: Do you now see how $P(n)$ is defined? $P(n)$ is effectively the first $n$ groups in this expression. So that's why $\frac{1}{2}$ is included in $P(2)$, and $\frac{1}{4}$ in $P(3)$. Moreover, by grouping them this way the right answer should quickly become apparent.

Comment: @Bram28 I understood that just after putting the question so now I have edited the question to the actual point where I have doubt.

Comment: It really should be pretty easy with these groupings ... I will provide no further hints, sorry! Time for you to do a bit of work yourself, or else you'll never become a good mathematician.

Comment: @Bram28 I got the solution/proof by your help. But I would still love it if you provide the solution. BTW thanks for hint it really helped me reach the solution.

Comment: @Sangeeta Cool, good work!  And Derek Luma's proof below is just fine

Comment: $P(n)\sim n\ln 2$ so the answer is (A)

Comment: Do you understand the proof I wrote?

Comment: @Derek Luna yes, I got the solution. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are still having trouble.

The following is a proof by induction fleshing out the ideas from previous users:

It can be seen that it is possible that

$P(1) = 1$ for $n= 1$ and

$P(n) < n$ for all $n > 1$.

The case for $n=2$ is clear since $P(2) = P(1) + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}   < 2$

Suppose $P(n) < n$  for some $n > 1$.

Then $P(n+1) = P(n) + \frac {1}{2^n} + \frac {1}{2^n+1}+...+\frac {1}{2^{n+1}-1} < n + \frac {1}{2^n+1}+...+\frac {1}{2^{n+1}-1} $.

Notice that $2^{n} + 2^{n} = 2^{n+1}$ so that it may be clear to you that there are $2^{n}$ of these terms. Then since the terms are decreasing,

$\frac {1}{2^n} + \frac {1}{2^n+1}+...+\frac {1}{2^{n+1}-1} < \frac{1}{2^{n}} +...+\frac {1}{2^n}<1. $

Therefore $P(n+1) = P(n) + \frac {1}{2^n} + \frac {1}{2^n+1}+...+\frac {1}{2^{n+1}-1} < n + \frac {1}{2^n+1}+...+\frac {1}{2^{n+1}-1} = n+1$.

Then this implies that $P(100) < 100$, $(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a pattern,
P(1) = 1

P(2) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 = P(1) + 1/2 + 1/3

P(3)                 = P(2) + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7
.
.
.

now, we need to find the limit of P(n), from observation.

P(1) =1  <=1

P(2) = P(1) + (<= 1/2 + 1/2)   <= 2

P(3) = P(2) + (<= 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4)   <= 3

P(n) < n [we can remove the equality sign actually]
=> P(100) < 100 and also P(200) < 200

Similarly, we can also conclude P(n) >= 1 + 0.5*n + 1/($2^n$ - 1)

Comment: You have just concluded P(n)<n by observing P(1),P(2) & P(3). I want proof. For me maths is about proves.

Comment: @Sangeeta there's a proof in the argument by rishav. Be patient and work it out. This is a good demonstration that you need to read carefully and understand. 

Additionally, math is not always about proves. It's about observations and ideas.

Comment: @Sangeeta; First of all, you asked " What to do Next " so I assumed, you needed hints. Just try to look at the observation, we can use P(n-1) to compute P(n). Now the question is How?, P(n) = P(n-1) + 2^(n-1) other terms. Now again you would observe that these last 2^(n-1) terms can be utmost at most 1 after summation. Try to look along these lines and pieces will fall into place. If not, @Derek Luna has mentioned the complete solution.

Comment: I was not being rude. It was just that I wanted proof. Because just on basis of observation you can't come to any conclusion, until proven. Btw thanks for solution. It really helped me.